# How to calculate the ticket price

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

First of all, this is my assignment question, and I was totally struggling for 2 weeks. If I want to calculate the ticket price, but the first three ticket price is 50, and the subsequence ticket is 45, but I tried do while loop, while loop and for loop, it will start over the program and start with the price 50, so how do I change the price to 45 when the program loop for 4 times?

```
public void setPrk(){
    int[] ticket_add= new int[9999];
    ticket_amount= ticket_add.length;
    Ticket ticket= new Ticket();
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    ticket.setTicketAmt();
    for(int i=0;i<ticket_amount;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter your choice (T/W/A): ");
            prk=s.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            
            
            while(!(prk=='t'||prk=='T'||prk=='w'||prk=='W'||prk=='a'||prk=='A')){
            System.out.println("Invalid option, try again");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            prk=s.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        }
        switch(prk){
            case't':
                ticket.setAge();
                Ticket.ThemePark();
                break;
                
            case'w':
                ticket.setAge();
                Ticket.WaterPark();
                break;
                
            case'a':
                ticket.setAge();
                Ticket.AllPark();
                break;
                
            default:
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("Your ticket fee will be "+(sum+(sum*0.06)));
    }
}

public char getPrk(){
    return prk;
}
public void setTicketAmt(){
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your ticket amount: ");
    while(!s.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println("This is not an integer, try again");
    System.out.print("Enter your ticket amount: ");
    s.next();
    }
    ticket_amount=s.nextInt();
    while(ticket_amount<=0||ticket_amount>9999){
        System.out.println("Invalid ticket amount, try again");
        System.out.print("Enter your ticket amount: ");
        while(!s.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("This is not an integer, try again");
        System.out.print("Enter your ticket amount: ");
        s.next();
    }
    ticket_amount=s.nextInt();
    
    }
    
}

public static int getTicketAmt(){
    return ticket_amount;
}

public static void ThemePark(){
    double[] ticket= new double[2];
    double ticketSize[]={0};
    if(age<17){
        if(ticket_amount<=3){
            ticket[0]=50;
            ticketSize[0]=ticket[0];
        }
        if(ticket_amount>3){
            for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
                ticket[0]=50;
                ticketSize[0]=ticket[0];
            }
            for(int i=0;i>3&&i<ticket_amount;i++){
                ticket[1]=45;
                ticketSize[0]=ticket[1];
            }
        }
        for(int k=0;k<ticketSize.length;k++){
            sum+=ticketSize[k];
        }
        
}
}
```

Comment: Please visit Help Center and learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [provide minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

The question is vastly unclear.

I assumed you tried to put in most relevant parts. However, some important variables are missing (e.g., `age`), and unrelated parts (e.g., the `switch(pkg)`) could  be removed from your question.

On the other hand, if that is all of the source code, it is best to state what are you trying to do in which functions.

Anyway, I presume you are trying to work on the price in the `ThemePark` function, and here's my solution to it:

```
public double ThemePark(int age, int ticket_amount) {
    // I used a double variable to store the total value, but the `static` attribute
    // is removed for demonstrating a whole function.
    double ticketSum = 0;
    if (age < 17) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ticket_amount; i++) {
            // The above fucntion of `for(int i=0; i>3&&i<ticket_amount:i++)` is genuinely
            // incorrect, as i would never increment to i>3 in such case, it should be set
            // as `i=4`. However, in such case it cannot registered the ticket_amount=4. As
            // a result, it should also be set as `<=ticket_amount`.
            if (i <= 3) {
                ticketSum += 50;
            } else {
                ticketSum += 45;
            }
        }
    }
    return ticketSum;
}
```

Please state in the question if there's more specifications, and I hope this answer helps.